# How does a Go function without return values modify data?

Tags: go

I don't understand how the bubbleSort() slice `a` be applied at the main().

I don't give a `return a` and don't write a global variable.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func bubbleSort(a []int) {
    var temp int
    for j := 0; j < len(a); j++ {
        for i := 0; i < (len(a) - 1); i++ {
            if a[i] > a[i+1] {
                temp = a[i]
                a[i] = a[i+1]
                a[i+1] = temp
            }
        }
    }
}

func inputNums() []int {
    var input int
    var number int

    fmt.Scan(&input)
    s := make([]int, input)

    for i := 0; i < input; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&number)
        s[i] = number
    }
    return s
}

func outputNums(b []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        fmt.Print(b[i])
        fmt.Print(" ")
    }
}

func main() {
    nums := inputNums()
    bubbleSort(nums)
    outputNums(nums)
}
```

Comment: Your bubble sort does not modify `a`_itself_ . All it does is order its elements.

Comment: slice is `pass by reference`, it will modify the original input

Comment: @Toxnyc: In Go all arguments are passed by value. The slice descriptor, a struct, is passed by value as if by assignment. The slice desriptor contains a pointer to its underlying array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `src/runtime/slice.go`
>
> ```
> type slice struct {
>   array unsafe.Pointer
>   len   int
>   cap   int
> }
> ```

---

In Go all arguments are passed by value. The slice descriptor, a struct, is passed by value as if by assignment. The slice descriptor contains a pointer to its underlying array.

`func bubbleSort(a []int)` receives the `a` argument by value but uses the pointer `a.array` to modify the underlying array elements.

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)